# OpenGL & ROS - mapping visualizer

Tags: c++, opengl, ros

I am new to modern OpenGL. I am working on a project build a simple 2d mapping system for my robot and I am using OpenGL to do visualization. Right now I can get data from the robot but I don't know how to draw the map with the data coming in. One problem is that the data is coming in continuously, how should I specify the buffer size? Also how can I tell OpenGL that my data is changing?

Here is a my code snippet:

```
std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point32> pts;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GLuint vertex_buffer, vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
    GLint mvp_location, vpos_location, vcol_location;
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Window", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window) {
        std::cout << "window creation failed\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    //mesh
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pts) * pts.size(), &pts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //shader
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    mvp_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    vpos_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
    vcol_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vCol");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_location);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vcol_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vcol_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void*) (sizeof(float) * 3));
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(program);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_location, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*) mvp);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pts.size());

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

right now it doesn't draw anything.

edit: I do have data coming in from robot and saved in `pts`

Comment: Of course it isn't drawing anything. You didn't give it anything to draw; `pts` is empty. Unless there's some code out there that you're not showing, you haven't actually provided any data to the buffer object.

Comment: I saved all the data coming from the robot in `pts`, but `pts` was indeed empty when I called `glBufferData`